# ajax to refresh whole page on occasion using the onclick event

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onclick

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="input"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="button" onclick="function(input.value);"/></td>`;
```

written in php. it's all in a table which is in a form. The function is executed properly, sends the data into a new php file and is running some data validation tests displaying some (error) messages according to these test results.

if the input is correct, i want the code to insert the value into a database and refresh the whole page. The data is being inserted, but the page is not refreshed.

I use this at the end in order to refresh but it doesn't seem to work:

```
echo '<script type=text/javascript language="javascript">document.location.href="page.php"</script>';
```

Comment: I think you're missing a semicolon after the last function call.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the similar problem and do not have an idea as well

Comment: no, nothing yet. i'm still trying though

Answer (score 1):

So you send some data back to an php file and in the event that some conditions are not met you send back some error messages, in the case they are met, cant you just simply use:

```
header( "Location: page.php");
exit;
```

Comment: seems like a good option, if i don't get a "headers already sent" message.. i'll try it and let you know! thanks a lot

Comment: no, that didn't work. it just displays the whole page.php in the div that holds the AJAX outputs..

Comment: Oh dear, in that case try and send back the js which includes parent.document.location or from memory it might be parent.opener.location... sorry to be vague, but I dont have time to mock this up at the moment.